# Lightbulb Popup in Intellij

Tags: intellij-idea

I like the Intellij Lightbulb popup, but it always seems to appear right when I'm about to click in the editor content, showing up at the worst possible time and the worst location.

Anyone know how to either set a longer delay before the Lightbulb shows up or how to reposition it so it is farther out of the way?

Answer (score 0):

You can disable it completely at Settings (Preferences on macOS) | Editor | General | Appearance | **Show intention bulb** and use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd> instead to show it when needed.